# How do I move my default virtual bridge to my NIC team

Tags: networking, virtualization, qemu

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been asked to spin up a host server for some VMs.  My Ubuntu 22.04 server OS is installed and I have my hypervisor installed and working.  I can even create VMs that can access the outside world and everything up to this point seems great.

My issue is I have four 10gig NICs in my host and I created a team with three of the four.  Now, I'd like my default virtual bridge (virbr1) to be attached to the team rather than the single NIC that is attached to when I did the hypervisor install.

I'm using QEMU to manage my VMs.

I would appreciate some help with this please. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your /etc/netplan/xxx.yaml file?